# Convert JPG raster format to TIF format

Tags: arcpy, convert, geotiff-tiff, jpg, error-000732

I have a large number of rasters (JPG format) and I want to convert them to TIFF format to folder called "OtherFormat" in env.workspace with arcpy. In my code I try to convert all JPGS using [Raster To Other Format (Conversion)](https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001200000032000000) and understand that I can do it if I write the exact name of the raster. But I have 120 rasters so I tried to use asterisk:

```
import arcpy,os,sys,string
import arcpy.mapping
from arcpy import env

env.workspace = r"C:\Project\out"
arcpy.RasterToOtherFormat_conversion("*.jpg","OtherFormat","TIFF") 
print 'converted'
```

but get the following error:

```
ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.  
ERROR 000732: Input Rasters: Dataset *.jpg does not exist or is not supported Failed to execute (RasterToOtherFormat).
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make a list of the jpeg's and the n loop trough them.
You can use the glob module for that:

```
import arcpy, os , glob

outworkspace = r"C:\Project\out\OtherFormat"
listOfJPG = glob.glob( r"C:\Project\out\*.jpg")

arcpy.RasterToOtherFormat_conversion(listOfJPG , outworkspace ,"TIFF") 

print 'converted'
```

Comment: warrieka,i get en error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\yaron.KAYAMOT\Desktop\stack 1.py", line 10, in <module>
    arcpy.RasterToOtherFormat_conversion(jpg, name,"TIFF")
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\ArcPy\arcpy\conversion.py", line 2753, in RasterToOtherFormat
    raise e
ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000732: Output Workspace: Dataset 2015-03-25_084900.jpg.tif does not exist or is not supported
Failed to execute (RasterToOtherFormat).

Comment: RasterToOtherFormat_conversion takes a list as input and a workspace as output. I mistook it for Raster_copy. I edited my solution.

Comment: arcpy.ListRasters("*","JPG") is possibly better in this case, it  does not require the user to download glob. First set arcpy.env.workspace to the folder the rasters are in and then returns a list of all the JPEG raster files.

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate through each file in your directory and call the function on each filename:

```
import os
in_direc  = 'C:\raster_loc'
out_direc = 'C:\converted'
for file in os.listdir(in_direc):
    #check to make sure it's a jpg
    if 'jpg' in file:
        #you need to change the parameters of this function call accordingly
        arcpy.RasterToOtherFormat_conversion(file,"OtherFormat","TIFF")
```

Comment: or os.listdir works to :)

Comment: camdenl,nothing converted with your code and also no error happened. i replace (file,"OtherFormat) with arcpy.RasterToOtherFormat_conversion(in_direc,out_direc,"TIFF")

Comment: Perhaps reading the method documentation will help next time ;)