# Convert tif raster format to jpg format

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, raster-conversion, geotiff-tiff, arcgis-10.3

Continusly to [Convert jpg raster format to tif format](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/140842/convert-jpg-raster-format-to-tif-format), i try to convert tif file to jpg:

```
import arcpy, os , glob

outworkspace = r"C:\Project\out\OtherFormat"
listOfFiles = glob.glob( r"C:\Project\out\*.tif")
arcpy.RasterToOtherFormat_conversion(listOfFiles , outworkspace ,"JPEG") 
print 'converted'
```

the result is:

```
>>> 
converted
>>>
```

and the tif file isn't converted. I work with arcview 10.3 and when i run the convert tool i get this message and cannot run the tool: 
[image]

Comment: What happens when you try to convert a single TIFF file to JPEG without having `glob` in the loop?

Comment: got the same result : "converted" without any converted raster

Comment: Try running it from the tool dialog and editing your question to include the parameters entered and the output in the results window.  Also, what version of ArcGIS for Desktop are you running?

Comment: i edited my question now

Comment: It looks like your raster has an invalid format. Have you tried adding it to a blank map to see if it will draw?  I suspect it will not.

Comment: i try now convert png file to tif-it also failed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22466/discussion-between-y-y-c-and-polygeo).

Comment: Do you have multiband rasters or single band?  Float or integer?

Comment: The reason it prints "converted" is because you need to wrap the call in a try/except block.  Perhaps [reading](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001200000032000000) the documentation will help.

Comment: Aaron,it's  multiband rasters